# Detect all PHP functions also with line break

Tags: php, regex, function

I have a script with a regex, which detect all defined internal functions in php. The script is working well, but there is a problem with the linebreaks.

With this script I searching for internal and defined funtions from PHP. Every function have to be replaced with the new function "no_function()".

```
$functions=get_defined_functions();
for($i=0;$i<count($functions["internal"]);$i++){
    //Include array functions
    if($functions["internal"][$i]=="array"||$functions["internal"][$i]=="array_push"){
    }else{
        $code=preg_replace('#('.$functions["internal"][$i].'[ |\n|\r|\t]*\([ |\n|\r|\t]*.*\))#i',"no_function()",$code);
    }
}
```

When I had a function like:

```
str_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

The function will not called because it will replace with *no_function();*

It will work normally. But if I have a function like that:

```
str_replace($search,
$replace,
$string);
```

The regex don't detect that, but PHP will execute that as well. I am a noob with regex. Can someone help me?

Thanks for every response.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Take the time to well explain what you are trying to do. Add an example input and the corresponding output. I can't be categorical at this time but I feel you are trying to do something the wrong way.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. I had updated the question and I hope it is now more understandable.

Comment: Replace `.*\))#i'` with `.*?\))#si'`. But it is definitely a poor way of approaching the problem, you just need a right parser.

Comment: Sorry but not really, I think you must take a look to the tokenizer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Comment: Dare I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your use case.  But you could use namespaces and redeclare internal functions under your namespace for a quick hack that will replace internal functions with no return.

First make a file consisting of dummy internal functions.

```
<?php
$funcs = get_defined_functions();
$output = "<?php\n";
$output .= "namespace example;";
foreach ($funcs['internal'] as $func_name) {
    $output.= "function $func_name () {}\n";
}
file_put_contents('dummy_funcs.php', $output);
```

Then in another file (perhaps a common bootstrap) include your dummy functions early.

```
<?php
namespace example;
include 'dummy_funcs.php';

echo str_replace('w', 'l', 'bawls');
```

Outputs nothing.

The upshot here is that you don't need to edit your code (other than adding the include). It could however be a pain depending on your existing namespacing.